# Rails: Include association with record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a simple way to return an association with a record?  My real use case is that a `Client belongs_to :location` and I'd like to return the client's location's name when I return the client.  In other words when I query for:

```
Client.find(x)
```

I'd like the response to include the location name:

```
=> #<Client id: 132, created_at: "2016-12-19 19:42:24", updated_at: "2016-12-19 19:42:24", location_name: "Blah">
```

when `location_name` is not normally part of a client.

Comment: Let's say `@client = Client.find(x)` you get location name with `@client.location.location_name` but I must miss something because it's a basic of object oriented programming. (Provided relationships are properly set in each model : has_one, belongs_to,... and that your migrations includes proper foreign keys being added) Can you develop a bit otherwise.

Comment: To be more specific: you can climb or go down a relationship tree easily. In this case I assume that location_name is a field in database table of model Location. Of course you can't navigate a tree with a has_many relationship as easily. Unless you specify to the very child you want to reach. For ex: `@user.books` return all books that you can parse in a view like `@user.books.each do |book| .... end` or you can refine among children like `@user.books.where(author: 'poe')` etc

Comment: Inmmy scenario I am working with a single `client` that `belongs_to :location`.  I basically want to do what a serializer does and return additional properties

Comment: Let's say you serialize your client into a hash. Why not adding the location name as a new item of this hash ? Just requires one extra line in your controller.

Comment: yeah I guess that would work